# Compare 2 tables of different lengths

Tags: arcgis-desktop, attribute-table, table

I have 2 Layers: Not_Joined and Joined

Not_Joined: Old digitized data that has X attribute in it.
Joined: Spatially joined layer that has the polylines with X attribute in in the table

Each row in "Joined" has a field that says  how many polylines of Not_Joined have been joined to the one element.

Goal: Compare the X attribute in both tables to give accuracy.

Problem: Table length in Joined is 4X bigger than Not_ Joined, so basic for loop will not work here.

---

Figured out part of it

Query Table from Joined Layer-> Join on Not_Joined based on X.
This seems to work well.

Comment: What are you comparing? The number of polylines joined? Or the accuracy of the X attribute?

Comment: I am comparing the X attribute. I have figured part of it out, and am currently using Model Builder

Answer (score 1):

If you want comparable table, you could start with a "summary statistics" of the largest table (Not_joined) based on the field X.

Then your table will be of comparable length and content (with a count in the summarized table)